# Adding pre and post treatment dummies in DiD regression

Tags: regression, dataset, difference-in-difference

I want to estimate the impact of economic sanctions on GDP and other macroeconomic indicators on Italy in 1935 with DiD. I have observations of GDP of Italy (treated) and of other countries (control) from 1929 to 1938. I created a time dummy equal to 1 if Year $\ge$ 1935 and a treatment dummy that is equal to 1 if the observation is for Italy (treatment group). I want to add pre and post treatment dummies for 3 years before and after the sanctions. My questions are:

1. Should I generate a dummy variable for every year pre and post treatment I want to consider? And how should the pre and post treatment dummies look like? For example, the pre-treatment dummy for 1934 (t= -1) should be equal to 1 only in 1934 and 0 in all other years, or it should be equal to 1 if year >=1934? And the post-treatment dummy for 1936 is equal to 1 only in 1936 or if Year >= 1936?
2. What should my regression look like with pre and post treatment dummies?

My dataset looks like this

[image]

Comment: The problem is one of saturation. If you fit an effect for each year, then you can't tell the difference between pre- and post- effect. Consider that if you omit the year-specific effect, then the "pre/post" binary variable summarizes the average response difference from post to pre period.

Comment: Why do you want to add three pre-/post-treatment time dummies? How long are these economic sanctions in effect?

Comment: I want to add pre-treatment time dummies to check if the parallel trend assumption holds, and post-treatment dummies to control for other effects unrelated to economic sanctions and evaluate how long the effects of economic sanctions last